# Отображение большого количества полигонов через ObjectManager в Яндекс картах

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Есть задача отображения большого количества полигонов, до ~ 5 000 - 7 000 на вьюпорт.

В настоящий момент это реализовано через создание инстанса `ObjectManager`.

При изменении bounding box карты (изменение координат центра, изменение зума) - происходит получение массива данных с бэкенда, удаление предыдущего массива из `ObjectManager` (методы `removeAll` или `remove`), и повторное добавление данных в ObjectManager (метод `add`). Это необходимо, поскольку полигон с теми же координатами (или `id`) между запросами может менять свое отображение (заливка цветом например).

На кол-ве полигонов >= 3000 начинаются заметные проблемы с перформансом, даже на мощных машинах. В частности, очень заметна длительная работа метода `ObjectManager.removeAll`.

Другой подход (с загрузкой сразу всего объема доступных данных) применить не можем - объем большой, а проблемы с перформансом проявляются примерно такие же.

1. Есть ли оптимальный способ решения подобной задачи с отображением тысяч полигонов на карте? При условии, что получать данные мы хотим чанками. Чанк = то, что помещается во вьюпорт.
2. Можно ли использовать какой-то другой способ удаления объектов из `ObjectManager`, который будет работать быстрее? (пробовали удаление самого менеджера из `maps.geoObjects`, создание нового инстанса со свежим набором данных - появляются проблемы другого рода)

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

ObjectManager не подходит для такого объёма работ. Вам следует попробовать [более производительные решения](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/many-objects.html) - LoadingObjectManager, RemoteObjectManager или даже Слой активных областей.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Мы, конечно, смотрели на указанные инструменты.  Поскольку согласно [таблице](https://tables.hostmeapp.com/restaurants/16458?utm_source=google&utm_medium=maps) разницы в производительности между ObjectManager, RemoteObjectManager, LoadingObjectManager нет, то в настоящий момент приняли решение посмотреть на ObjectManager. Отсюда и появившиеся вопросы.

Comment: Вы не правы. Разницы не может не быть. Каждый последующий метод всё сильнее снимает нагрузку с клиентского устроства. ObjectManager оперирует объектами на стороне клиента, но не все отрисовывает. LoadingObjectManager уже не всё клиенту выгружает. RemoteObjectManager уже и кластеризацию переносит на сервер. А активные области - фактически просто тайлы - нагрузка самая незначительная.

Comment: Ссылка прикрепилась некорректная, прошу прощения. Ссылка на [сравнительную таблицу](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/many-objects.html#many-objects__advantages). Спасибо за пояснение, но все равно оно оставляет замечания. 1. Если загрузка данных на клиент реализована оптимальным образом, то почему object manager оказывается медленнее для UI, чем loading object manager? 2. Наверное, имеет смысл расширить и уточнить документацию, чтобы подобных вопросов не возникало впредь.